# poster post form with unselected file input field

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a form with a bunch of text input fields, and a file input field for the user's CV:

```
<input id="cv" name="cv" accept="application/pdf" type="file" value=""/>
```

This field is not mandatory so whenever a user posts the form without selecting a file, the server-side logic will not delete any previous uploaded CVs stored in the database.

I've noticed that when I don't select a file with my browser and I post the form, the POST request payload looks like the following:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryaxaKZBvja5RsdU6h
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="lastName"

Smith
------WebKitFormBoundaryaxaKZBvja5RsdU6h
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cv"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundaryaxaKZBvja5RsdU6h
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="country"

USA
```

I am now using the [poster](https://atlee.ca/software/poster/) module to stress-test my application. I use *poster* to submit a post using the standard multipart/form-data encoding. I use it more or less like this:

```
opener = register_openers()
fields = {'lastName': 'Smith', 'cv': open('cv.pdf'), 'country': 'USA'}
datagen, headers = multipart_encode(fields)
request = urllib2.Request('account-submit', datagen, headers)
result = opener.open(request)
```

The above works and posts the form, including the CV. What I am now trying to achieve is to post the form using the *poster* module without providing a CV and creating the exact same POST payload as before.

I have tried:

```
fields = {'lastName': 'Smith', 'cv': open(''), 'country': 'USA'}
```

… and a number of variations such as:

```
'cv': open(None)
'cv': open(None)
'cv': open([])
'cv': None
```

… but none of them seem to work. The only thing that works is omitting the 'cv' field altogether and while I can get that to work, it requires changes in my server-side logic as the latter expects the request payload for a CV field that's not "filled" to be exactly as shown above, i.e.:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryaxaKZBvja5RsdU6h
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cv"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

------WebKitFormBoundaryaxaKZBvja5RsdU6h
```

How can I achieve that using the *poster* module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poster is going to interpret the object provided based on the attributes available. You can see the source code for the logic that duck types the object as a file here:

https://bitbucket.org/chrisatlee/poster/src/97d3c6fcb87785d1838549301f0092dec4229abf/poster/encode.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#encode.py-173

As you can see, it's looking for something that has a `read` method. If it does, it treats it like a file and uses the octet-stream encoding you are trying to achieve.

Here are two simple ways to get an emptyish file.
This one is the cleanest because it doesn't rely on the os/filesystem.

```
import StringIO
...
my_empty_file = StringIO.StringIO()
fields = {'lastName': 'Smith', 'cv': my_empty_file, 'country': 'USA'}
```

If that doesn't work (it's hard to be sure without testing it), you can pass it an actual empty file:

```
fields = {'lastName': 'Smith', 'cv': open('/dev/null'), 'country': 'USA'}
```

Comment: `open('/dev/null')` did it.